# Importing gensim

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I've installed gensim, however I keep getting an error when I try to import it
`from gensim.models import Word2Vec`
ImportError: cannot import name 'open'

I'm using the updated version of gensim 3.8.0 and smart_open 2.1.0.

I have reinstalled several times but still can't get it to work.

Comment: The latest released version of gensim is 3.8.3. If you're sure you've upgraded to that version, and are still having a problem, please edit your question to include details of how you've installed things (& verified the versions in use), and show the full error message with traceback (source code & files involved in the error).

Comment: Are you using mac, linux or windows? I got Gensim to work on mac and linux. But I can't get Gensim to work on windows.

Comment: Did you manage to find the root cause?
Same issue happen to me (mac0

Comment: I did, try conda install gensim==3.7.3
conda install smart_open==1.8

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, after that I found a solution:

```py
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

You can install first , then you can import:

```py
import gensim.downloader as gensim_api 
import gensim
```

Works for Mac.